# Compatibility between Qt and Boost sockets libraries

Tags: c++, qt, networking, boost-asio

In my work, I'm developing a Viewer client for a Offshore simulation server, using sockets to send the simulation data from the Simulator to de Viewer.

But, the server uses Boost.asio as it's sockets library. As the client uses Qt for it's GUI, I was wondering if there is any problem in using de Qt Networking library for handling the sockets. Is there any compatibility issues?

Thanks in advance, and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be any "compatibility" problem. You only have to implement the communication protocol agreed with the server side correctly.

Comment: It's possible he's asking if there's issues merging a Boost.asio built client library and the Qt GUI socket tools.

Comment: I don't think so. He says asio is used on server, and he needs to develop the client side.

Answer (score 2):

I had no trouble building an application that used both Qt and Boost.Asio. Everything was compiled/linked in a single executable. It included a QtWebKit-based client talking to a Boost.Asio-based server over HTTP.

Now, this was only a sample app. You don't need to use both in the same application. As long as client and server agree on the protocol, there shouldn't be any issues.